# Static variable being fed into JTextfield is only JTextfield that I am failing to update. Can't figure out why but I think it's a scope issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a simple game and have my main method inside my GUI class and have managed to get rid of all my issues with JTextfields not updating from my game loop that way except for one which coincidentally is the only one that is being fed a static double variable instead of raw strings. I can't seem to find out why online or by tinkering and finally broke down and decided to ask my first stackoverflow question.

```
   public class BlackJackWindow extends JFrame
   {
       static double betAmount = 0;
       static double money = 100; //The offending variable
       static int playerAction = 0;`
```

Here is the kind of situation I am using it in that seems to do nothing when called.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BlackJackWindow gui = new BlackJackWindow();

        //Initializing main deck
        Deck theDeck = new Deck();
        theDeck.newDeck();
        theDeck.shuffle();

        //Dealing hands
        Deck playerHand = new Deck();
        Deck dealerHand = new Deck();

        money = 100.00;

        while(money > 0)
        {
           gui.moneyField = new JTextField("Money : " + money); //This line 
           seems to never occur on my GUI, what am I doing wrong?
           gui.moneyField.validate();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just creating the JTextField object and assigning it to a variable **does not place it into the GUI**, and in fact I'd recommend against trying to create a GUI in this way. Note that this has nothing to do with the static money field and all to do with creating a GUI in the wrong way.

What you probably want to do is to **get** the currently displayed JTextField and setting its text with the value held by money, but hard to say given the small amount of code you've posted.

Also this has nothing to do with scope and again all to do with references. You may be assuming that setting a field, here the `gui.moneyField` will change the JTextField displayed in the gui GUI, and that's not how references work.

Note that this answer is incomplete because your question and code is incomplete, in particular, we do not see how you create your GUI or how your variables relate to the problem at hand, it's all a mystery to us. For a better answer, please post a better and more complete question, one with a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program post.

So not:

```
gui.moneyField = new JTextField("Money : " + money); //This line
```

but rather

```
gui.setMoneyText("Money : " + money);
```

where the method body within the GUI class could be something like:

```
public void setMoneyText(String text) {
    moneyField.setText(text);
}
```

Also the while loop doesn't belong in event-driven GUI programs, but that's the subject of another answer to another question.

Comment: Adding the setter method solved my problem but it seems I need to learn more about event driven programming and how references work since I don't fully understand why it works now.